# How to create our own Category for Visual Studio Properties Window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, designer

I have been adding designer extensibility to my custom control. I can create category editor using "Microsoft.Windows.Design.PropertyEditing.CategoryEditor". But the Target Category is something weird. I can only add my custom editors to existing categories like Common, Text, Layout, transform, etc.

How can I create my own like "My Custom Control 3D Properties"

Regards,

Jawahar

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to do it by putting tags in the code above the property, for example (C++/CLI):

```
[Category("Nooo")]
[Description("They'll laugh at you")]
property int Mom;
```